# Using Google Charts API with PHP-sourced values

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to pull data from PHP arrays and then feeding them into an X-Y Line Chart using Google Charts API (by converting the data to JSON first).

First, I have my two arrays of X and Y values in PHP:

```
$hit = array(1,2,3);
$hit2 = array(3,4,5);
```

I then have an array that interlocks the array values (like a zipper):

```
$count = count($hit);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$subArray[] = '[' . $hit[$i];
$subArray[] = $hit2[$i] . ']';
$superArray = array($subArray);
```

I then converted this to JSON by:

```
var num = '[' + <?php echo json_encode(array_values($superArray)); ?> + ']';
```

And I then included this in my Google chart by adding the following line:

```
data.addRows(num);
```

However this is not rendering.

var num returns:

```
[[1,3],[2,4],[3,5]]
```

...which is definitely the 'right' format for the Google Chart I'm trying to produce.

Test: 
If I manually test by replacing that line with:

```
data.addRows([[1,3],[2,4],[3,5]]);
```

then it works perfectly, but not when it's

```
data.addRows(num);
```

Any thoughts, please? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `console.log(num)` I guess it's returning a string? 
Try adding JSON.Parse to convert your JSON-string to a javascript object.

`var num = JSON.Parse('<?php echo json_encode(array_values($superArray)); ?>');`